# how to create pinterest layout?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm trying to achieve Pinterest layout in my app, and i tried the tutorial from [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2). my problem how to implement to UICollectionView cellForItemAt and heightForPhotoAtIndexPath

here my code:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GaleryCollection", for: indexPath) as! GaleryCollectionViewCell
    let imgGalery = self.galery![indexPath.row]
    if imgGalery.photo != nil {
        cell.imageGalery.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: imgGalery.photo!)!)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Check GitHub for examples and learn from their code: [swift](https://github.com/search?l=Swift&langOverride=&o=desc&q=pinterest+layout&repo=&s=stars&start_value=1&type=Repositories) / [obj-c](https://github.com/search?l=objc&langOverride=&o=desc&q=pinterest+layout&repo=&s=stars&start_value=1&type=Repositories)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same tutorial inside my project.  I am using this delegate function.  You'll need to import AVFoundation.  If you are pulling your images from a database it will be better for you to set the image's height and width inside your DB to easily recall them as I have below.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAt indexPath: IndexPath, with width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    let postHeight = posts[indexPath.item].postImageHeight
    let postWidth = posts[indexPath.item].postImageWidth
    let postSize = CGSize(width: postWidth, height: postHeight)
    let boundingRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
    let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: postSize, insideRect: boundingRect)

    return rect.size.height
}
```

I am now facing an issue when appending objects though. :/